# CRUD function w/ view history of deleted items using React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, crud, browser-history

I'm new to these things... Well, I want to create a CRUD function of certain items with view history of deleted items using reactjs and firebase as database. I saw some tutorials of CRUD in reactjs but I'm really having a hard time where i will delete items in the list and the deleted items will go to the history table. I just want a sample code to that function. Thank you.mm

Comment: please consider posting the link to the tutorials you are referring to so that we can understand what function you are talking about

Comment: here is the tutorial 
 https://www.djamware.com/post/5bc50ea680aca7466989441d/reactjs-firebase-tutorial-building-firestore-crud-web-application

well it is working, i just don't know how to add the "view history" function where when i delete the items, the items deleted will go to the history.... View history function may somehow similar to the browser history